# Python Linter or intellisense or pylance in VSCode not working in server path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, lint, pylance

in the last week, I had a problem with my VsCode, I'm developing Python RPA and the lint (pylance) didn't work in the local server path, does not identify the function, and the possible errors

[Program in the local server path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEnXm.png)

But if I code the same program in the my computer path (example Desktop), works!

[Program in the desktop path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mUOV.png)

python v: 3.11.5
pylance v: 2023.9.30
vscode v: 1.82.2

Server Type: Microsoft Server

A possible problem is the UHC host error, but, I fixed in the %appdata%/Code/user/config.json and the error persist

I tried reinstalling the python, reinstalling and update the vscode but noting

I code a same program in another language (Typescripy) in the local server path but works
[Typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVfLE.png)

I installed the python and vscode with python extension in another computers but the same errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)